# Getter for boolean variable with maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am working to generate stub files from xsd. However the stub files generated have boolean getters generated as isXX() instead of getXX().

```
public class Task{
  @XmlAttribute(
    name = "IsFailure"
  )
  protected Boolean isFailure;

  public Boolean isIsFailure() {
  return this.isFailure;
  }
}
```

How can i modify the boolean variables getter names? I need to generate getIsFailure() istead of isIsFailure()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enableIntrospection` option in maven plugin.